# Regular Expression for inline Comments Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am using a regular expression to filter out the commented code

`"(/\*([^*]|(\*+[^*/]))*\*+/)|(//.*)"`

The problem with this expression is that it will filter out inline comments such as

```
public const string UpdateFileProcessRequestWithModifiedBy = "usp_Update_File_Request_Status_Modified_By"; // this one updates file_process_request and file_details table with the current status and Modified By
```

How can I ignore the inline comments (comments at the end of the line) using regular expression.

I doing this using a PowerShell script which reads the content of the file which has PATHs in it and then read the content of those paths and do a `Select-String`

```
$isConstantFile = [bool]($fileContent |
        Select-String -Pattern "\bConstants.cs\b" |
        Select-String -Pattern $dirPattern |
        ForEach-Object{
            Get-Content $_ | 
            Select-String -Pattern $filePattern | 
            Select-String -Pattern "(/\*([^*]|(\*+[^*/]))*\*+/)|(//.*)" -NotMatch -Quiet #Regex for comments
        })
```

Comment: So to clarify, you want to exclude lines that do not contain any code, i.e. the whole line is a comment, but you want to include lines that have code mixed with inline comments?

Comment: @Slartiprefect yes that is correct!

Comment: It may be difficult to do on a line-by-line basis. Problems that come to mind: multi-line comments between /* and \*/ or string constants that contain /* or //.  If you are confident that the input doesn't have these, then the following pattern might work: `"^\s*((/\*([^*]|(\*+[^*/]))*\*+/)\s*|(//.*))$"` . This is essentially the same pattern, but fails the match if anything other than whitespace precedes or follows the comment.  See mklement0's answer for something that handles multi-line comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```bash
@'
/* 
 block comment, multi-line
*/

int i = 1;

/* block comment, single-line*/

// Single-line, stand-alone
   // Ditto with indentation

int j = 1; // Only keep this one

/**/
'@ -replace '(?sm)/\*.*?\*/[ \t]*(?:\r?\n)?|^[ \t]*//[^\r\n]*(?:\r?\n)?'
```

Note:

- The key part is `^[ \t]*//` in combination with the multi-line regex option (`(?m)`, in its inline form), which makes `^` match at the start of each line: it makes sure that `//` comments are only removed if they are the beginning of a line, optionally preceded by in-line whitespace.
- The regex is complicated by also trying to remove the subsequent newline along with the comment; if that isn't needed, it can be simplified to:

  - `(?sm)/\*.*?\*/|^[ \t]*//[^\r\n]*`

Output:

```bash
int i = 1;


int j = 1; // Only keep this one
```

For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/LjZ6Gp/5).

Note:

- To incorporate this regex into your command, you can *not* use *line-by-line* processing the way you do now (`Get-Content $_ | Select-String ...`), because the regex needs to match *across lines*.
- A simple way to remove the comments of interest from a given file would be 
  `(Get-Content -Raw $_) -replace '...'` (where `'...'` represents the regex above).
- Some general notes on PowerShell's regex support:

  - PowerShell's regex features, which build on .NET's regex APIs, are *case-insensitive by default*
  - .NET regexes don't have the concept of a global flag (`g`).
  - Whether PowerShell's behavior is in effect global (i.e. action on *all* matches of a given regex) depends on the feature used; e.g.:

    - `-replace` is implicitly global, `-match` is not.
    - `Select-String` is only fully global if you use the `-AllMatches` switch.